# How can i crop multiples image with source directory and store it in same directory after cropping with same name?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have try this code where `alstFileName` stores the names of files store in source directory:

```vb
For Each _file As String In alstFileName
     Dim image As Bitmap = New Bitmap(_file)
     Dim rect As New Rectangle(539, 345, 168, 124)
     Dim cropped As Bitmap = image.Clone(rect, image.PixelFormat)
     cropped.Save(_file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Next
```

It's give me error at line

```
cropped.Save(_file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

tell me that A generic error occurred in GDI+.

What i should do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try calling `image.Dispose()` before `cropped.Save()`.

Comment: ya it's working thank you for reply.